# Is the Rayleigh criterion in any way related to Rayleigh scattering?

Tags: optics

The wavelength of light should be very much greater than the particle size scattering the light in Rayleigh scattering.
And the Rayleigh criterion deals with the ability to resolve two objects as separate.
But are the two related in anyway. Could I use Rayleigh scattering principles to derive the Rayleigh criterion?

Comment: Why do you think they should be related?

Comment: They *are* related; they were discovered by the same person. What makes you think that there is any further connection?

Comment: Both deal with situations where the odd behavior of light when interacting on a small scale.  That both were discovered by the same person also suggests that they might both result from some similar understanding of the behavior by the same human mind.  I don't think it's unusual that this question is asked, and I don't think comments that ask why a question should be asked are helpful or respectful.